# Dagger 2 subcomponent across Android modules

Tags: android, module, dagger-2

Recently I started to divide our application into smaller Android modules, but I can't figure out how to structure dagger so it works for me.

My approach is to divide "bigger" features into smaller modules. Most of my features is within a `base` module for now.

What I have working right now:

```
         App
          ^ 
          |
         Base
          ^
          |
      Mvvm core
```

MyDagger setup consists of:
- a `@Singleton` scoped `AppComponent`
- a `@UserScope` subcomponent `UserComponent`

Both of which is placed in the `Base` module.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
         App
          ^ 
          |
Feature 1 - Feature 2
          ^
          |
         Base
          ^
          |
      Mvvm core
```

My plan is that each feature will have a `@FeatureX` subcomponent within their own module - but this is where everything falls apart.

I can't figure out how to expose the `SubComponent.Build` to each of my feature modules.

Is this even the right approach or what am I missing?

Bonus info: I have also tried to move the `AppComponent` & `UserComponent` into the `App` module, but then I lack access to the component, which I need for injection, from my feature module(s).

Comment: what does a feature contain: activity, utility class, models?

Comment: Yes, everything that feature needs to function.

Comment: so if I get your right, your feature module needs to access your app dependencies and you app also needs to access your feature subcomponent?

Comment: No. My feature module will contain a subcomponent, which parent is in the base module (The AppComponent). But my problem is that, to be able to create a subcomponent, you need the parent component

Comment: you don't need access to the parent component to build a subcomponent

Comment: Huh.. can you show an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184755/discussion-between-benjamin-and-eixx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've created an android module named cookie which contains an activity and a dagger module.

CookieActivity:

```
class CookieActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var name: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cookie)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name).text = name
    }
}
```

CookieModule:

```
@Module
abstract class CookieModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun cookieActivity(): CookieActivity

    @Module
    companion object {

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideName() = "Oreo"
    }
}
```

Now you want to use this `CookieActivity` from your main application. First you need to create your `AppComponent` (note that the `CookieModule` is installed inside the component):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, CookieModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App>
```

Then make your `Application` class able to inject activity and fragment:

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var dispatchingActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var dispatchingFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>? {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment>? {
        return dispatchingFragmentInjector
    }
}
```

You can now use your `CookieActivity` and the main application will take care of the injection:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CookieActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

"Oreo" will be shown as provided by the `CookieModule`.